# Undefined variable: SerialException

Tags: python, exception, serial-port, pyserial

I am using the pySerial library to have a Python script log data from an Arduino. I am trying to handle the SerialException when the script cannot connect to the port you provided, and Eclipse says "Undefined variable: SerialException". Is there something I forgot to import?

Code:

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
    connected = 1
except SerialException:
    print "No connection to the device could be established"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want:

```
except serial.SerialException:
   ...
```

in python, `Exception`s are classes derived from `Exception`.  So, when a module/package defines it's own custom exceptions, they usually get [imported in the module/packages's namespace just like the other classes/functions](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.SerialException).  This said, putting a:

```
from serial import SerialException
```

at the top of your file would probably also do the trick.